# WebStorm Alt+Enter (show intentions) doesn't work

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

As a starter in web-development Alt+Enter (show intentions) is one of the most used feature, it tells me what to do and saves me a lot of time.

I've reinstalled my OS few days ago and unfortunately updated WebStorm to the latest version (I'm not a huge fan of keeping everything updated, developers screw-up in every update and I'm afraid of that), and now for some reason Alt+Enter stopped working.

There must be some kind of bug because I've tried to change the shortcut but neither one of Ctrl, Alt, Shift keys worked only the normal letters.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the EAP release and the bug is gone.
You can grab it from here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP